# How to fix jackson java 8 data/time error?

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

```
Java 8 date/time type `java.time.LocalDateTime` not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling
```

I have been getting this error in my spring boot project that uses gradle. I added the below given gradle dependancy for jsr310 as well, still it didn't work.

```
implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.13.3'
```

How can I fix this error? My project uses java 17 and spring 2.6.7. Thanks!

Comment: What did your search turn up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

Hope, this helps you.

Answer (score 11):

`JavaTimeModule` should be registered explicitly:

```java
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration { 
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

The first solution should be used with `jackson-datatype-jsr310` versions `2.x` before `2.9`. Since you added version `2.13.3`, the module should be registered as shown below, according to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69811985/10231374).

```java
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration { 
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return JsonMapper.builder()
            .addModule(new JavaTimeModule())
            .build();
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2:

> Starting with Jackson 2.2, Modules can be automatically discovered
> using the Service Provider Interface (SPI) feature. You can activate
> this by instructing an ObjectMapper to find and register all Modules:

```java
// Jackson 2.10 and later
ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
    .findAndAddModules()
    .build();
// or, 2.x before 2.9
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.findAndRegisterModules();
```

For reference: [jackson-modules-java8 - Registering modules](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime#usage)

Comment: This did not work either mate.

Comment: Are you still getting the same error, `Java 8 date/time type java.time.LocalDateTime not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling`?

Comment: @Kalindu I didn't see the version of the added module in the first place. I added a solution that will work with `2.13.3`.

Comment: So I'm using com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.4 && jackson-datatype-jsr310 version: '2.14.1' and the above isn't working for me. Any suggestions

Comment: @MetaCoder Have you tried the second solution? I also added a solution for automatically discovering and registering modules.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me @birca123 do you mean update 2 when you say the second solution?

Comment: I've tried this: 
```@AutoConfiguration(before = JacksonAutoConfiguration.class)
public class JacksonConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                .findAndAddModules()
                .build();
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `@AutoConfiguration(before = JacksonAutoConfiguration.class)` with `@Configuration` and use either code you pasted or code from the "UPDATE" section.