# Unable to set up a simple Redis + Spring project: "Java 8 date/time type `java.time.Instant` not supported by default"

Tags: java, spring, redis, jackson, spring-data-redis

and many thanks for your help in advance! I am trying to set up a simple Spring + Redis project, using IntelliJ, and sadly it just doesn't work.

I have checked countless forum posts here, but sadly to no avail. Whilst many of them are somewhat related, they are not the same, and I was unable to use the insights provided to my particular situation.

For convenient reproduction of the issue, I am listing every step of what I did below:

#### Project Setup

1. Start IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.4 (Ultimate Edition)
2. *File -> New -> Project... ->* **Spring Initializr**
3. Language: **Java**
4. Type: **Gradle - Kotlin**
5. Click *Next*
6. Spring Boot: **3.1.4**
7. Select: **Lombok** + **Spring Web** + **Spring Data Redis (Access+Driver)**

### Application properties

8. I added the following  to `application.properties` in `src/main/resources`:

```
spring.data.redis.host=localhost
spring.data.redis.port=6379
```

*(Note that Redis is running locally in a container and I tested that it works fine / is reachable on port 6379)*

### Custom data class

9. Right-click main package (in my case `com.example.demo`), and click *New -> Java Class*
10. Name the class `MyObject` and add the following:

```
package com.example.demo;

import lombok.Data;

import java.time.Instant;

@Data
public class MyObject {
    Instant timestamp;
    String textPayload;
}
```

### Configuration class

11. Right-click main package (in my case `com.example.demo`), and click *New -> Java Class*
12. Name the class `AppConfig` and add the following code:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, MyObject> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory factory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, MyObject> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(factory);

        // Serialization for keys. By default, it uses JdkSerializationRedisSerializer
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());

        // Serialization for values. By default, it uses JdkSerializationRedisSerializer
        // Here, we use Jackson to convert MyObject to JSON
        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());

        return template;
    }
}
```

### Create controller

13. Right-click main package (in my case `com.example.demo`), and click *New -> Java Class*
14. Name the class `MyController` and add the following code:

```
package com.example.demo;

import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.experimental.FieldDefaults;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.time.Instant;

@FieldDefaults(makeFinal = true, level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
public class MyController {
    RedisTemplate<String, MyObject> redisTemplate;

    @GetMapping("/save")
    public ResponseEntity<String> saveObject() {
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
        myObject.setTimestamp(Instant.now());
        myObject.setTextPayload("some data");
        redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("myObject", myObject);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Object saved");
    }

    @GetMapping("/read")
    public ResponseEntity<MyObject> readObject() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("myObject"));
    }
}
```

---

## Result

The above will then lead to the following exception when trying to call the `/save/ endpoint:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Java 8 date/time type `java.time.Instant` not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling (through reference chain: com.example.demo.MyObject["timestamp"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1308) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnsupportedTypeSerializer.serialize(UnsupportedTypeSerializer.java:35) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeWithType(BeanSerializerBase.java:655) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.TypeWrappedSerializer.serialize(TypeWrappedSerializer.java:32) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:479) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:318) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._writeValueAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4719) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(ObjectMapper.java:3987) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.serialize(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:220) ~[spring-data-redis-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.rawValue(AbstractOperations.java:128) ~[spring-data-redis-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultValueOperations.set(DefaultValueOperations.java:236) ~[spring-data-redis-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at com.example.demo.MyController.saveObject(MyController.java:24) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

### Solution approach #1

My first attempt was to follow the advice given in the exception message: "*com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Java 8 date/time type `java.time.Instant` not supported by default: **add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling** (through reference chain: com.example.demo.MyObject["timestamp"])*"

So I added the following line to my `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310")
```

...and hit the Gradle reload button / press *Ctrl + Shift + O* in IntelliJ

**Result: the same exception as above.**

### Solution approach #2

Keeping the newly added dependency in there for good measure, I attempted several other solution approaches suggested here on Stack Overflow.

#### Add a bean for the `ObjectMapper` singleton in my configuration

Source: [Spring Boot 2.5.0 and InvalidDefinitionException: Java 8 date/time type `java.time.Instant` not supported by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67874510/spring-boot-2-5-0-and-invaliddefinitionexception-java-8-date-time-type-java-ti)

```
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        return objectMapper;
    }
```

**Result: same exception as above.**

### Solution approach #3

#### Another variant for an `ObjectMapper` singleton

Source: [How do I enable the JSR310 support for LocalDate using Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69811740/how-do-i-enable-the-jsr310-support-for-localdate-using-jackson)

```
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return JsonMapper.builder()
                         .addModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                         .build();
    }
```

**Result: same exception as above.**

### Solution approach #4

#### Specify bean for `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`

Source: ChatGPT's suggestion [image: Configuring ObjectMapper]

```
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder() {
        return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().modules(new JavaTimeModule());
    }
```

**Result: same exception as above.**

---

## Help?

I tried many other things, spending quite some time on this problem, but nothing would work. Can it really be that hard to serialize Instant's with Spring/Redis? What am I missing? Can someone help?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you're manually creating the `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer`. When you do that, it automatically creates a new ObjectMapper that isn't set up through Spring and has no auto module loading capability. A quick fix would be to either inject the ObjectMapper into your `redisTemplate` bean function or make an ObjectMapper right inside the function and then hand it over to the `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer`'s constructor. This should sort things out. By the way, going the injection route is a good idea since it lets you use the default and globally set up ObjectMapper. And just a heads up, don't forget to include the `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310` dependency.

So a good solution can look like this:

```java
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, MyObject> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory factory, ObjectMapper mapper) {
    RedisTemplate<String, MyObject> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(factory);

    // Serialization for keys. By default, it uses JdkSerializationRedisSerializer
    template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());

    // Serialization for values. By default, it uses JdkSerializationRedisSerializer
    // Here, we use Jackson to convert MyObject to JSON
    template.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(mapper));

    return template;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Dennis, thank you so much - this already seems to have brought me one step closer to the solution! I am curious, when you said *"I noticed you're manually creating the GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer"*, could you elaborate on what the "automatic" way would be in this context? Currently, I am looking for the most plain and simple implementation, so maybe my manual creation of that `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer` is indeed not even necessary at this stage?

Comment: `@EnableRedisRepositories` should automatically configure a `RedisTemplate` for you. However it will enable a few other things as well.

Comment: Thank you. Would you have a general recommendation of when to use one over the other? I am trying to understand the pros and cons of each approach...

Comment: If you're handling it yourself, you'll need a new RedisTemplate bean for each class you're serializing to redis. If you only have a few classes, doing it manually is okay. There are advanced ways like using InjectionPoint to generalize it, but that's a deeper topic.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to help!